# How does a website-admin see a user-agent?

Tags: java, http, https, user-agent, urlconnection

In Java, you can set your user-agent when connecting using the URLConnection class. I have tried searching to see how a user-agent is categorized and shown to a site admin, but didn't find what I was looking for.

```
URLConnection uconnect = new URL("http://sample-website.com").openConnection();
uconnect.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Program information and contact information");
```

If a user-agent is set like above, when setRequestProperty tells the server that what it is sending is a user-agent, what does that look like in raw text? After the server has received the user-agent, typically, how does the user-agent show to a human? Can you use html formatting in a user-agent? Can you use \n to break lines, or will that end the user-agent and the server receive the following lines as unrecognized jargon?

Comment: _"what does that look like in raw text?"_ - what any HTTP header looks like - name, followed by a colon, optional white space, followed by the value. URL encoding applied where necessary.

Comment: _"After the server has received the user-agent, typically, how does the user-agent show to a human?"_ - "typically" - not at all. Some scripts gathering visitor statistics might display it in some place, when requested.

Comment: _"Can you use html formatting in a user-agent? "_ - what for? I would consider any tool that shows user agent headers and does _not_ properly escape that to be broken, resp. vulnerable for possible XSS attacks.

Comment: For some websites that have an API will request that you put your site username in your user-agent so they can contact you if the program is causing problems. In those cases, presumably a human would need to be able to read the individual user-agents in a connection log or similar. These cases are what I am primarily referring to. +1 for useful and relevant info

Comment: Then put the contact info in there in plain text. I don't see how HTML would be helpful in that context at all.

Comment: I already have the user-agent setup properly in the project I'm working on, I'm just looking for more understanding for future projects.

Comment: Ok, but again, I think using HTML in there makes little sense - most tools that display the UA in any context should filter/escape this (otherwise, it could be a possible XSS attack vector.) So if you put any HTML in there, that might actually show in the odd amateurishly written script ... but for the most part, it should have no effect.

Comment: Understood. Why I asked.